# How to rename a project in the Team Foundation Server (TFS)

Tags: windows, sql-server, sharepoint, team-foundation-server

How to rename a project in the Team Foundation Server 2008? What are khown issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Team project cannot be renamed in TFS v1

You may use the following workaround (sort of workaround, because you won't really end up with renamed project with identical contents):

1. Create new project with desired name
2. Copy work items from old project to a new one (one-by-one, as there is no bulk copy option).
3. Move all source control folders from under old project folder to a new project folder
   Sharepoint portal documents cannot be moved in bulk (as far as I know), so you do that manually
4. Move of source code will retain the files history, and work items will also have partial history, but overall I would say the workaround does not worth the labour (and Sharepoint docs will not have their history). At any rate, selecting right name in the beginning beats any workaround by far.

[Source](http://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2006/10/renaming-team-project.html)

Comment: Renaming a Team Project is also not supported in the latest version of TFS currently in development (TFS 2010).  Therefore probably best to just stick with the name you have unless it is really bad.

Answer (score 4):

You can't rename a project name even in TFS 2010.

However, the renaming feature is often requested. Go here and vote for this feature to force Microsoft to put it in next version of TFS.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/554539/cant-rename-a-team-project-in-tfs-2010

Comment: Voting was closed: "Due to current priorities, the product team decided to postpone the resolution of this item."

Answer (score 2):

I think renaming is one of the most sought after features.  Unfortunately, as mentioned above, there is no contextual menu to do a site rename.  If you don't utilize the work items or the sharepoint features, the built in move command will be your best bet.  You will, as mentioned above have to create a new team project with the desired name.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can't rename a Project from within TFS, there are now easier ways to accomplish the whole Move files, Copy/Paste Work Items steps outlined previously:

> [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)

If you download the release from the [Visual Studio Tools Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f854dd59-8eeb-4673-8d9a-ae012989bfa2) this will allow you to move source control items with history, as well as work items to a new project - indeed the initial Hands On Lab included in the documentation walks you through this exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can now rename a team project on Visual Studio Online and in the upcoming TFS 2015 release: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/tfs/administer/project-rename

Comment: That link has been moved or renamed :(